# AnyLogic - models behind the Road Traffic library

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

Is it released ,What are the mathematical models behind the Road Traffic library of anyligic simulation software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get in touch with Andrey Malykhanov via LinkedIn. He created the basic models for his PhD, and they were improved into the final car library.

cheers